# Service is not starting up in android

Tags: android, android-service

I am using following code

```
startService(new Intent(Loading.this, AppService.class));


public class AppService extends Service 
{       
    private Timer timer;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) 
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() 
        {
            @Override
            public void run() 
            {
                SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                          "UserSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                boolean isLoggedIn = customSharedPreference.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);
                if (isLoggedIn)
                    updateContact();
            }
        },0 , 120 * 1000);  
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        return Service.START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

     @Override
     public void onDestroy() 
     {
         super.onDestroy();
         timer.cancel();
         timer = null;      
     }
```

Nothing is happening , the debugger won't even enter in Service. No OnCreate or any other thing getting called.

Comment: Did you made the entry in manifest.

Comment: Probably you don't have the service in your manifest. Examining LogCat (via adb logcat, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse) should turn up some warnings that may help.

Comment: Nothing shows up and its in Manifest. confirmed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you don't have the service in your **manifest**. Examining **LogCat** (via adb logcat, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse) should turn up some warnings that may help.

Comment: I have added      <service android:name=".AppService" ></service>

Comment: Check the full path. Check if the manifest package and Service package is same. Better include full path

Comment: just a suggestion, should call super in each function like super.onCreate();